# How to find a file in a folder and its subfolder

Tags: find

I just need to find a jssecacert file in a directory and its sub directories down the line.
I have tried command below but it didn't work

```
find . -name "jassecacerts"
```

Comment: Which was the filename you wanted to find again?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a typo in your command - `find . -name "jassecacerts"` should probably be `find . -name "jssecacerts"` instead (note that an extraneous `a` has been removed).

Comment: Sorry for the the typo but it didn't work. still no result found

Comment: Then maybe the file isn't there. How do you know that the file is in the directory you think it's in? How do you know the file exists at all? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?